# Atajo para comentar código en android studio - teclado español

Tags: android, android-studio

¿Cuál es el atajo para comentar código en android studio?.

Mi teclado es en español y no tiene la barra "/". Y como sistema operativo uso Ubuntu.

[image: Mi teclado en español]

Comment: haz mirado la tecla 7?

Comment: @ArtEze esta pregunta existe en so en inglés y está relacionada con la programación.

Comment: @PabloClaus Pon el enlace, y si tiene respuesta mejor.

Comment: @ArtEze http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523490/comment-shortcut-android-studio Si bien es más general, demuestra que es una pregunta válida la de chambito

Comment: @PabloClaus El problema es que no tiene la barra (`/`)... Quizás la solución sea la combinación `Control` + `Fn` (la primera inferior izquierda) + `7` .

Answer (score 3):

Puedes editar el atajo de teclado a tu preferencia en la configuración del IDE.
En este caso, yo puedo comentar con los siguientes atajos.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Configure para comentar de la siguientea manera:en línea con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Se comenta en

Opcion 1 :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Ocpion 2 :

Tienes el [link aquí](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) de todos los atajos.

Ocpion 3 :

```
File -> settings -> Buscas "Keymap"
```

Y lo pones como quieres o ves como lo tienes configurado.